# Clear origin url

Tags: git, git-clone

Usually I start to work with new project from GIT this way:

```
git init
git remote add origin https://myurl.git
git clone
```

But what if I have entered wrong URL before `git clone` and now wont to clear it and add new one?

What is command that does that?

Answer (score 1):

Use git `remote set-url`:

```
git remote set-url origin https://myurl.git
```

Comment: this means I can use it in future instead of 'git remote add origin' ?

Comment: If you want to add it the first time use `git remote add origin`.  If you want to change the URL of a remote you already defined, use `git remote set-url origin`.